# How to call an MSI file from another without being a part of the caller installer with WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a little issue which is that I have to call an MSI file from another MSI file.

Both of them are independant meaning that they don't belong to the same installation.

Is it possible to make it with CustomAction ?

I know it's possible if I use bootstrapper but I can't do it this way.

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MySetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Sofiane" UpgradeCode="c151e7ab-b83a-445f-93b2-2ab7122ea34b">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Property Id="EXEPATH" Secure="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MySetup" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
    <Binary Id="InstallTools" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)InstallTools\bin\$(var.Configuration)\InstallTools.CA.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="SetupProps" BinaryKey="InstallTools" DllEntry="OpenExeUrl" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="yes" Return="check" />
    <CustomAction Id="OpenExe" Return="ignore" Directory="exeDirectory"  ExeCommand="&quot;[EXEPATH]&quot;" Impersonate="yes" Execute="deferred"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="SetupProps" Before="OpenExe"/>
      <Custom Action="OpenExe" After="InstallExecute"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MySetup" />
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="exeDirectory" FileSource="@(EXEDIR)" />
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="myAppFile">
        <File Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <ComponentRef Id="myAppFile" />
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

In the custom action OpenExe, EXEPATH is the second MSI file to call.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start it from CA you can use

```
var process = Process.Start(filePath);
```

But i'm not sure if it will be good with you?

Btw. i'm not sure it will cause problems with installation, maybe you should call your CA with `After="ExecuteAction"` parametr, i was doing it some time ago, the only thing i recall is that i had problem with *please end 1st installation* error, that code fix it i belive.

Comment: the second MSI file is launched only one time...when I want to relaunch it doesn't work.

Comment: You want launch it more then once? I think i don't understand your question, can you explain?

Comment: You can't launch any installer before you do not end install currently one! I created msi, that call for OpenOffice.exe installer, i added only `process.WaitForExit();` When my msi installer install my product, it (before endDlg shows) start OpenOffice.exe and let it install

Comment: Please check my second answer you will see what I've done. Please advice.

Comment: Start that CA in `InstallUISequence` `After="ExecuteAction"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63225/discussion-between-sofiane-and-buzka91).